# Binding of 2 Comboboxes to Dict<string, string[]>

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a datastructure like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, string[]> AvailableFiles { get; private set; }
```

Think of a list of directories and their files. I would like to be able to select files by first selecting a directory with the first `ComboBox`. After having selected a directory the 2nd `ComboBox` should show the available files. Changing the selected item in the 1st `ComboBox` should change the items in the 2nd `ComboBox`.

This should be possible somehow, but I have only done simple WPF bindings until now. What I have so far is this.

```
<ComboBox
    x:Name="CbFirmwareVersion"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Manager.AvailableFiles}"
    SelectedIndex="0"
    DisplayMemberPath="Key"
    SelectedValuePath="Value"
    Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
    Margin="{StaticResource DefaultContentMargin}" />
<ComboBox
    x:Name="CbFirmwareFile"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Manager.AvailableFiles}"
    SelectedIndex="0"
    DisplayMemberPath="Value"
    SelectedValuePath="Key"
    SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=CbFirmwareVersion, Path=SelectedValue}"
    Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
    Margin="{StaticResource DefaultContentMargin}" />
```

The first `ComboBox` shows the directories correctly. The 2nd `ComboBox` shows `String[] Array, String[] Array....` as items instead of the values of the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the first Combobox's SelectedItem to a Property of your ViewModel and bind that Property's Value

```
<ComboBox
...
SelectedItem = "{Binding Path=SelectedDirectory, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

In your ViewModel then you will have to have

```
KeyValuePair<String,String[]> SelectedDirectory {get;set;}
```

in the Second ComboBox

```
<ComboBox
x:Name="CbFirmwareFile"
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedDirectory.Value, Mode=OneWay}"
SelectedIndex="0"
Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
Margin="{StaticResource DefaultContentMargin}" />
```

There is still some Plumbing to do, for PropertyChanged. But this should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. This works once the setter of SelectedDirectory raises the PropertyChanged event.